# Comparing and reducing difference between two numbers regardless of which is larger

Tags: python, built-in

I'm using the `abs` built-in function to measure the difference between two numbers regardless of whether `x` is bigger than `y` or vice versa.

For example, if `y = 5` and `x = 7`, the result will be `2`. If `y = 7` and `x = 5`, result will still be `2`.

But if I want iterate until the result is `0`, is there a way I can use `abs` or a different built-in so that `y` or `x` can be incremented or decremented so that the result will be `0`?

I like the `abs` function, but it seems a shame to write code that has to check whether `y` is bigger than `x` or vice versa so as to increment or decrement until the difference is `0`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to end up with `x = 6` and `y = 6`, or do you not care as long as both are equal? What have you tried - for example, why not pick one, increment it and then switch to decrementing if the difference gets larger?

Comment: `x, y = sorted([x, y])`, now always treat `x` as the smaller value...!?

Comment: Thanks, may try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if x > y: x, y = y, x   # swap x and y if x > y
for x in range(x, y+1):
    diff = y-x
```

is pretty simple. Notice that one `if-statement` saves you `N` calls to `abs` (where `N = abs(y-x)`). So I think you should prefer the `if-statement` instead of trying to avoid it.

---

Since you didn't specify if you wished to increment (the smaller) or decrement
(the larger) presumably by one, you might be only interested in the difference. In that case, you
could use:

```
for diff range(abs(y-x), -1, -1):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this.

Answer (score 1):

In case you really want to avoid conditional statements:

```
while abs(x-y) > 0:

    # do something

    sgn = (x-y)/abs(x-y)
    x += max(0, -sgn) - max(0, sgn)
```